# FadeIn all Elements except this

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, fadein

I am a little confused with my following example:
I solely want to overlay all my td elements except 'this', so basically invert what is currently happening. Not the hovered td shall be overlayed, only the others. Can someone possibly help me?

```
$('td').hover(
function() {
var overlay = $('<div class="overlay">' + '</div>').hide().fadeIn(500);
$(this).find('.td-hack').append(overlay)
},
function() {
$(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut(500);
}
);
```

I built my current code on Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EbV2C/3/

Thank you for your time, Cheers

Comment: hmmm... then shouldn't you instead add the overlay to all td's by default, then when you hover over one, hide the one in the hovered cell?

Comment: I don't think that will do the trick, this is what I am aiming for: http://www.cambio.de/campaign/spring-summer-2013.html

Comment: If you trying to do same effect on something similar and is using table for non-tabular data, I'll smack you ;P For that, better use what that example is doing, using floated `lis`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('td').hover(    
    function () {
        var overlay = $('<div />', {'class' : 'overlay'});
        /* looking at the sibling elements of the current 'td',
           which explicitly excludes the current 'td'; looking
           within those 'td' elements for the '.td-hack' elements,
           iterating over those with the 'each()' method: */
        $(this).siblings('td').find('.td-hack').each(function(){
            /* appending a clone of the overlay element (otherwise
               that would be appended, on the first iteration and
               subsequently moved, hiding it, fading it in: */
            $(this).append(overlay.clone().hide().fadeIn(500));
        });
    },
    function () {
        $(this).siblings('td').find('.overlay').fadeOut(500);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EbV2C/6/).

Or, slightly differently:

```
$('td').hover(
    function () {
        var overlay = $('<div />', {
            'class': 'overlay'
        });
        /* much as above, but not using 'each()', instead passing
           an anonymous function to 'append()': */
        $(this).siblings('td').find('.td-hack').append(function(i){
            return overlay.clone().hide().fadeIn(500);
        });
    },
    function () {
        $(this).siblings('td').find('.overlay').fadeOut(500);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EbV2C/9/).

To mask all cells (or to *append an overlay to all cells*) within the whole `table` other than the `this` node:

```
$('td').hover(
    function () {
        var overlay = $('<div />', {'class' : 'overlay'});
        $(this).closest('table').find('td').not(this).find('.td-hack').each(function(){
            $(this).append(overlay.clone().hide().fadeIn(500));
        });
    },
    function () {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td .overlay').fadeOut(500);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EbV2C/13/).

Or:

```
$('td').hover(
    function () {
        var overlay = $('<div />', {
            'class': 'overlay'
        });
        $(this).closest('table').find('td').not(this).find('.td-hack').append(function(i){
            return overlay.clone().hide().fadeIn(500);
        });
    },
    function () {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td .overlay').fadeOut(500);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EbV2C/14/).

And, finally, (for modern/up-to-date/standards-compliant browsers), an `addClass()` solution, using the following CSS:

```
td {
    /* changes follow: */
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
.td-hack {
    /* no changes here */
}

td.transparency {
    /* added this: */
    opacity: 0.4;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('td').hover(
    function () {
       $(this).closest('table').find('td').not(this).addClass('transparency');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td.transparency').removeClass('transparency')
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EbV2C/16/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).
- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: +1 for [`Siblings()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/siblings). That's what I was doing on jsfiddle ;P

Comment: Wow, that was fast David, thanks. If my table has actually more than one row, how would I solve that?

Comment: The number of rows doesn't make any difference at all ([first code](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EbV2C/11/), [second code](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EbV2C/10/)), since the jQuery events are bound to `td` elements, not the `td` elements of a specific row.

Comment: @DavidThomas I think he actually asked that if you hover one td, all other td's should get overlayed regardless of row. By the way, we gotta fix that `clone()` of yours. Each td is getting stuffed with lots of `.overlay` divs.

Comment: @Raphael: ah, that would probably make more sense. Though I'm becoming a little scared as to the objective/use of this `table`, now...

Comment: @DavidThomas According to OP, he's trying this: http://www.cambio.de/campaign/spring-summer-2013.html I'll smack his head if he's trying to do the same with a `table`. I did one that works but `fadeTo()` is tricky because makes others flash a bit when hovering from one to another. http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/EbV2C/15/

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, it's basically just to make things fancy, that's it. @RaphaelDDL, how else could I do it?

Comment: I like the final solution, absolutely awesome, thank you @DavidThomas

Comment: @TimothyDalton " how else could I do it? " - The same way of your source. By using UL > LI. At David: Btw, nice one with transitions :D +1

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best way to accomplish what you are trying to do..   Every time you hover, you are adding N new dom elements where N is the number of td-hack elements...

Why not just .animate the opacity of the other elements to "fade them out" ?

For example -

```
    $('td').on("mouseover", function() {
      $('td').not(this).css('opacity', 0.8);
    });

    $('td').on("mouseout", function() {
      $('td').css('opacity', 1.0);
    });
```

Comment: Your welcome.. If instead of .css you use .animate, you can also get the fadein/fadeout effect too...